# how to add items from a jtextfield to a jcombobox?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jcombobox

I use a `textfield` to add items to a `combobox`. When a button is clicked, I need the text in the `textfield` to be added to the `combobox` including previously added texts. I get the result, but the items in the `combobox` have square brackets. Here is my code:

```
DefaultComboBoxModel cb=(DefaultComboBoxModel) jComboBox1.getModel();
Vector v=new Vector();
v.add(jTextField1.getText());
cb.addElement(v);
```

How can I prevent the square brackets being added to the `combobox`?

Answer (score 3):

You're adding the whole vector as a single element. I think you just want to do:

```
cb.addElement(jTextField1.getText());
```